# Fast open pickle in Python3

Tags: python, pickle, shared-memory

I notice a fast unpickle method in [gork](https://github.com/xai-org/grok-1/blob/e50578b5f50e4c10c6e7cff31af1ef2bedb3beb8/checkpoint.py#L43).
Here is the code:

```py
@contextlib.contextmanager
def copy_to_shm(file: str):
    if file.startswith("/dev/shm/"):
        # Nothing to do, the file is already in shared memory.
        yield file
        return

    tmp_dir = "/dev/shm/"
    fd, tmp_path = tempfile.mkstemp(dir=tmp_dir)
    try:
        shutil.copyfile(file, tmp_path)
        yield tmp_path
    finally:
        os.remove(tmp_path)
        os.close(fd)

def fast_unpickle(path: str) -> Any:
    with copy_to_shm(path) as tmp_path:
        with open(tmp_path, "rb") as f:
            return pickle.load(f)
```

Is it helpful to copy the file into `/dev/shm/` before opening the file?
What size of files will benefit from it?